# libgdx: wrong touch handling on phone

Tags: java, android, input, libgdx, touch

foreword: on desktop everything works just perfect.
Trouble appers when i'm testing my project on phone

I start the game. Here is some buttons on screen: button_1, button_2, button_3. For example i'm touching button_1: with very first touch after app start nothing happing at all. If i'm touching button_1 again, it works fine -> touchDown (button image goes down for 10px) then touchUp (button image goes up for 10px and button code run). But if i touch another button instead, for example button_2, only touchDown of button_1 occurs (button_1 image goes down for 10px and up) and nothing else. It's happens for every button, so i need to touch button twice to make it work.

Button class:

```
public class myButton {

private float x, y, width, height;
private Texture buttonUp;
public Rectangle bounds;

private boolean isPressed = false;

public myButton(float x, float y, float width, float height, Texture buttonUp) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.buttonUp = buttonUp;

    bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
}

public boolean isClicked(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return bounds.contains(screenX, screenY);
}

public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    if (isPressed) {
        batch.draw(buttonUp, x, y - 10, width, height);
    } else {
        batch.draw(buttonUp, x, y, width, height);
    }
}

public boolean isTouchDown(int screenX, int screenY) {
    if (bounds.contains(screenX, screenY)) {
        isPressed = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isTouchUp(int screenX, int screenY) {
    if (bounds.contains(screenX, screenY) && isPressed) {
        isPressed = false;
        return true;
    }
    isPressed = false;
    return false;
}

}
```

InputHandlerer:

```
@Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        screenX = (int) touchPos.x;
        screenY = (int) touchPos.y;

        playButton.isTouchDown(screenX, screenY);

        return true;
    }
```

---

```
    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        screenX = (int) touchPos.x;
        screenY = (int) touchPos.y;

        if (playButton.isTouchUp(screenX, screenY)) {
            start();
            return true;
        }
}
```

in create() method i've got:

```
touchPos = new Vector3();

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputHandlerer());

camera = new OrthographicCamera();
viewport = new FitViewport(1080, 1920, camera);
```

in render() method i've got:

```
touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
camera.unproject(touchPos);

batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

I repeat - on desktop every button works properly, but on phone not. What could be the problem?

Comment: What is `playButton` in InputHandler?

Comment: @icarumbas
it's my button, so in create() method:

   
    `menuButtons = new ArrayList<myButton>();
    playButton = new myButton(0, 560, 602, 180, playButtonUp);
    menuButtons.add(playButton);`

Comment: Why don't want to use Scene2D library? Use Stage, set it as InputProcessor, and add Buttons to it. 
 There is no reason to implement your own Button class. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui

Comment: @Arctic45 thx for your advice, but the question is 'what could be the problem in this case'. And sorry for my incompetence in java/libgdx, i'm learning it through my project, maybe if i give up i will have to rethink on ur advice. I've almost done work, except this part, and making that simple button class is not big deal. Also, as i said, it works nice on desktop, so there is must be i missed something, that somebody might know what and could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe on desktop is working because you can do only one click at a time, instead on phone you should manage the pointers, also if you don't want to use the multitouch.

On your InputHandlerer class you have to initilize:

```
private int button1pointer = -1;
private boolean button1isPressed = false;
```

Then you have to manage the pointers on your tochDown/Up methods:

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {   //here you can choose how many touches you can manage
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {

       screenX = (int) touchPos.x;
       screenY = (int) touchPos.y;

       if (playButton.isTouchDown(screenX, screenY) && (button1pointer != i) && (!button1isPressed)) {
          button1pointer = i;
          button1isPressed = true;
       }
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    if (!(Gdx.input.isTouched(pointer)) && (button1pointer == pointer) && (button1isPressed)) {
       button1pointer = -1;
       button1isPressed = false;
       start();
       return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: not working. Still i need touch screen second time. But now no matter where u will touch that second time - button code will work after it.